# Mark appointment with custom icon in VSTO Outlook

Tags: outlook, vsto

I want to do something like this: I export calendar event from Outlook calendar, and when I do it, I want to mark this appointment with custom icon. I already tried custom forms, but it only marked this event inside it, that means when I open it I got my icon in top left corner, but I want this icon for example in month view, where are all appointments and I want to quickly see which are exported and which not (screen below, little icon should be on right side of these fields).
Can someone give any tip how to do it in VSTO? Or is it possible at all?[image: Example, I want little icon on right side of this fields]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that. The best you can do is change the appointment color.

Comment: Too bad :/ Colors are ofted use by Outlook users and I don't wanna change them only to mark this appointment. Can I maybe add a border to appointment? Or any other little effect, only to give information that this appointment has already been sent?

Comment: Nope, can't do that.